# Touch ID prompt showing up as portrait in landscape only app

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, orientation, touch-id

With the new iPads rolling out, I'm adding touch ID to our next app update. I have a landscape only app that always hides the status bar running on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8.

I have the touch ID code working fine, but the alert only appears as if the app were in portrait. The background behind the touch ID alert also throws up a portrait status bar.

1. Is it possible to display the alert in landscape at all?
2. Is there a way to not display that status bar?

I've tried messing with `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, but the touch ID alert doesn't seem to care or reference what the view controller is currently being displayed as.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The is an iOS 8 bug. I've checked on a few apps, including the iTunes Connect app by Apple and they all show it in portrait mode, even if the device is in landscape

<strike>This issue has been fixed in iOS 9</strike>

Update: This is still an issue in iOS 9

Update 2: This is still an issue in iOS10. As @nicolas-miara said, it seems like Apple expects you to use it in Portrait only

Comment: iOS 10 seems to be the same. At this point I would say it is "a feature" (i.e., Apple expects you to use it in portrait orientation only!).

Comment: Yeah, there is no way to show the Touch ID popup in landscape mode. But please comment here if you have a solution. Thanks!